# Netezza INSERT - ignore invalid dates?

Tags: sql, netezza

Is there an option or setting that will tell Netezza to ignore invalid dates ?  The entire INSERT fails in the example below because the 3rd row of the source table has an invalid date.  I would expect that the offending row may be skipped, but to insert zero rows seems a tad extreme.

I tried the following, but it failed as well.  The alternative is parsing the source date and verifying each component for validity ( including days/month, leap years etc.. )

```
insert into db.test ( cmclmn, effdt, efftm ) 
        select cmclmn, case when to_date(effdt,'yyyymmdd') is null 
                         then null 
                         else to_date(effdt,'yyyymmdd') end, 
               cast(lpad(efftm,6,0) as time) as efftm
          from db.test_src
          ;
```

Entire script:

```
CREATE TABLE db.test
(
        cmclmn integer,
        effdt   date,
        efftm   time
        )
DISTRIBUTE ON ( cmclmn );

drop table db.test_src;
create table db.test_src
(
        cmclmn integer,
        effdt integer,
        efftm integer)
        distribute on ( cmclmn );

insert into db.test_src ( cmclmn, effdt, efftm ) values  ( 1,20140120, 102000); 
insert into db.test_src ( cmclmn, effdt, efftm ) values  ( 2,20140121, 231212); 
insert into db.test_src ( cmclmn, effdt, efftm ) values  ( 3,0,111111 ); 
insert into db.test_src ( cmclmn, effdt, efftm ) values  ( 4,20140123 ,90909 ); 

insert into db.test ( cmclmn, effdt, efftm ) 
        select cmclmn, to_date(effdt,'yyyymmdd'), cast(lpad(efftm,6,0) as time) as efftm
          from db.test_src
          ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user defined function to do a full test.  For your case, perhaps some simpler things will do:

```
insert into db.test ( cmclmn, effdt, efftm ) 
    select cmclmn, to_date(effdt,'yyyymmdd'), cast(lpad(efftm,6,0) as time) as efftm
    from db.test_src
    where effdt between 20010000 and 20150000 and
          effdt % 10000 between 0101 and 1231 and
          effdt between 01 and 31;
```

I'm not sure if Netezza ever optimizes queries so the `to_date()` might run before the filter.  If so, then use `case` as well:

```
insert into db.test ( cmclmn, effdt, efftm ) 
    select cmclmn,
           (case when effdt between 20010000 and 20150000 and
                      effdt % 10000 between 0101 and 1231 and
                      effdt % 100 between 01 and 31
                 then to_date(effdt,'yyyymmdd')
            end),
           cast(lpad(efftm,6,0) as time) as efftm
    from db.test_src
    where effdt between 20010000 and 20150000 and
          effdt % 10000 between 0101 and 1231 and
          effdt % 100 between 01 and 31;
```

The date checking isn't perfect, but it might be sufficient for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Netezza Analytics Package 3.0 ships with some sample LUA functions, isdate() and todate() are two of the functions there.

Those functions trap the return code before it craps out the query.  isdate() returns a boolean result that tells you if the date is valid or not, todate() will return the Netezza date value or null if the incoming argument is not a valid date.

Thanks.